# Using relative Image path in Angular 2 and ASP.NET Core

Tags: c#, angular, typescript, asp.net-core

I was trying to get the path of a local image file, but I can't figure out where the relative paths are located. Normally I would get them out of wwwroot/images folder, but when I try to load them from there it fails.

Where do you get relative paths in Angular 2? I used generator-aspnetcore-spa to create the application.

https://github.com/aspnet/JavaScriptServices

http://blog.stevensanderson.com/2016/05/02/angular2-react-knockout-apps-on-aspnet-core/

For example in folder ClientApp/components/app/app.ts.
Where would I put the image folder and how do I call its path ?

Comment: I think it will be easier if you provide a github repo for your sample project and refer to the exact component and image file you are having issue.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the `Program.cs`

```
public class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var host = new WebHostBuilder()
            .UseKestrel()
            .UseContentRoot(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
            .UseIISIntegration()
            .UseStartup<Startup>()
            .Build();

        host.Run();
    }
}
```

the `UseContentRoot` defaults to the current directory from your app.

By calling `app.UseStaticFiles();` in the Startup class

```
public class Startup
{
    ...
    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env, ILoggerFactory loggerFactory)
    {
        ...
        app.UseStaticFiles();
```

the static file middleware is enabled. With default settings it will serve all files in the web root folder (`<content root>/wwwroot`).

If you look at the https://github.com/aspnet/JavaScriptServices Angular2 template, you will see in the webpack.config.js that the output is stored in

```
output: {
    path: path.join(__dirname, 'wwwroot', 'dist'),
    filename: '[name].js',
    publicPath: '/dist/'
},
```

so that is `<content root>/wwwroot/dist` and the URL will be

```
 http://<whatever host and port>/dist/<my file>
```

The URL does not have to contain `ClientApp` (content root level, not accessable by static file middleware) but `dist` (wwwroot level).

Therefore put your `images` folder into `...\wwwroot\images`and the image URL will be `http://<whatever host and port>/images/<my image file>`.

Answer (score 0):

IN .Net Core, the app needs to know to use static files, have you got

```
app.UseStaticFiles();
```

in the Startup.cs?